# How can I implement didSelectRowAt method without relying on indexPath

Tags: swift

So I'm very new to the Swift programming language and iOS development in general and I'm trying to implement a simple tableview for navigation.

I didn't like the idea of relying on the indexPath parameter to determine which action to perform in my code as changing the order of the cells will need me to go back and refactor the method too. so I was looking at implementing a multi-dimensional array to store my different items for the table.

This works absolutely fine for the cell contents but I'm running into issues when trying to implement the didSelectRowAt method.

**Note** this is all within a UIViewController class with the UITableViewDataSource delegate.

```swift
private let options: [[( title: String, action: (() -> ())? )]] = [
  [
    ("title" ,  action)
  ]
]

func action() {
   //perform logic here
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   guard let action = self.options[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].action else { return }
   action()
}
```

However I am recieving a build error:

> Cannot convert value of type '("MyViewControllerName") -> () -> ()' to expected element type '(() -> ())?'

What am I missing here? Is this even the best way to implement this method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that:

1 - action is a method not a simple function.

2 - you are using action before your view controller is actually instantiated (since it's in the init of a stored property).

So there is one simple way to solve your issue: 
Replace `private let options` 
by 
`private lazy var options`
for instance.

That way the options will be initialised after your ViewController so the `action` method will be available as a function.

Overall, it's not a bad idea to try to tie the action to your data.